# Encrypt in React Native and decrypt in node.js

Tags: node.js, react-native, cryptography, google-cloud-functions

I have an http request in which I want to pass some sensitive data so I'm trying to encrypt these data. Does someone have two modules, one in react-native and the other one in node.js ? I tried to use react-native-rsa and Crypto but I get a lot of errors, and I don't know if it's possible to use both together.

Comment: Want to send data to your server over http? Use https then.

Comment: I use https but is it really secured to pass sensitive data to Google Cloud Functions like this ?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. That's why we use https.

Comment: Alright, thank you for your advice

Answer (score 0):

I think you must try [Hybrid Crypto](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hybrid-crypto-js) once.